# React native nativemodules not defined when linking a library with it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

NPM version : 10
React-Native Library : react-native-get-music-files
(Using android)
Installation : 
    npm i --save react-native-get-music-files
    rnpm link

Things I Have Already Tried :
    rnpm link react-native-get-music-files
    react-native link
    npm install 
    react-native run-android
    REINSTALLING
    MAKING A NEW PROJECT

Details : 
    Its documentation says add import com.reactlibrary.RNReatNativeGetMusicFilesPackage; but when automatically linking , it adds com.cinder72.musicfiles.RNReactNativeGetMusicFilesPackage; 
Manually it is showing com.reactlibrary.RNReatN... is not found.
Automatically everything is working fine.

Error :
    In the react-native-get-music-files/index.js

```
import { NativeModules, Platform } from 'react-native';

const { RNReactNativeGetMusicFiles } = NativeModules;

const MusicFiles = {
    getAll(options){

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            if(Platform.OS === "android"){
                RNReactNativeGetMusicFiles.getAll(options,(tracks) => {
                    resolve(tracks);
                },(error) => {
                    resolve(error);
                });
            }else{
                RNReactNativeGetMusicFiles.getAll(options, (tracks) => {
                    if(tracks.length > 0){
                        resolve(tracks);
                    }else{
                        resolve("Error, you don't have any tracks");
                    }
                });   
            }

        });

    }
}
export default MusicFiles;
```

It says RNReactNativeGetMusic files is undefined.
I tried console log NATIVEMODULES and it shows nothing as RNReactNativeGetMusic or anything similar.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the docs hasn't been updated for V2.

```
import com.cinder92.musicfiles.RNReactNativeGetMusicFilesPackage;
```

the above should work fine.

Comment: Sorry but it didn't work. I tried many things earlier but it just keep on giving me the error. I tried linking and differnet things. I tried manually linking it. If you can give me a guide to follow like how you installed and how it worked

Answer (score 0):

You're probably following the linking instructions on the package's npm page, which are outdated. Follow the instructions on this [github repo](https://github.com/cinder92/react-native-get-music-files) instead.

Follow the steps for manual installation and don't forget to clean the code you previously added to link.

Then import it like this,

```
import MusicFiles from 'react-native-get-music-files';
```

Hope this helps you and feel free to ask any questions.